# Why ngOnChanges() does not trigger when @Input() update the data Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, lifecycle

parent.component.html

```
<parent-comp [data]="mydata"> </parent-comp>
```

parent.component.ts

```
this.service.abc$
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe.asObservable())
        .subscribe((data: myType[]) => {
            this.mydata= data;
        });
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input data;
```

**Under Class I have below code**

```js
public ngOnChanges() { if (this.data) { console.log(this.data); } }
```

Now I want whenever I receive latest data in `@Input data` from Parent Component to child then my `ngOnChanges` function should trigger and print data in console.

But unfortunately `ngOnChanges` function does not trigger again. It trigger only once when component initialize

Please let me know if anyone wants more detail on same!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show how the `mydata` variable is initialized and further assigned new values?

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]

Comment: Is your parent component ChangeDetectionStategy set to OnPush ?

Comment: If you pass down the same (complex, not primitive) object, but with different values, ngOnChanges will not be called. You have to re-create the object and pass it.

Comment: @MichaelD I updated my Question. Hope it help you to understand.

Answer (score 9):

Given the lack of further information, I'd make an informed guess that `@Input data` is either an array or an object.

According to [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges), `ngOnChanges` is:

> A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a
> directive changes.

What it doesn't say however is *how* the property should be changed. Generally speaking, the hook is only triggered when the reference to the property is changed.

Consider the following eg.

Parent component controller

```js
mydata = [];

updateMyData(value: any) {
  this.mydata.push(value);
}
```

Parent component template

```html
<app-child [data]="mydata"></app-child>
```

Child component controller

```js
@Input() data: any;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(changes);
}
```

Now you'd expect the `ngOnChanges` will be triggered every time the `updateMyData()` function is called in the parent component. But the reference to the variable `mydata` is never changed. So the hook won't be triggered. There are multiple ways to force the change detector to trigger the hook.

**Method 1:**
Bind the `@Input` decorator to a setter instead of the variable directly. Discussed in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63016169/6513921) already.

**Method 2:**
Use spread syntax to re-assign the variable in the parent component.

Parent component controller

```js
mydata = [];

updateMyData(value: any) {
  this.mydata = [...this.mydata, value];
}
```

You could use the same methods for objects as well.

Comment: Many thanks, this was quite useful to me. However I think that method 1 will not help in this case: the setter will not even be called, since the change detection will not trigger (I made the test, and only Method 2 worked)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you everyone for your quick and effective solutions.

I got solution and it is not exactly but similar to what you guys suggested.

In the Parent Component:

```
**Earlier I was assigning this way**
`this.mydata= data;`


**But now I am assigning in below way:**
`this.mydata= cloneDeep(data);`
```

Note : `cloneDeep` is imported from `lodash`

Comment: Yeah. This is what we usually do. Clone it with some way. either using lodash - clone deep, or the spread operator, or the natural longer way with JSON parse and stringify :)

Answer (score 2):

NgOnChanges will only be triggered for an input-bound property change of primitive type. That is because the reference to the data-variable has to be changed in order for the change to be registered, so that you can get it in this life-cycle hook.

So, the possible way you could achieve this is by changing the reference of 'mydata' variable. Like, assigning a new reference to the mydata variable when it is changed, `mydata = [...mydata]` if it is an array, or `mydata = {...mydata}` if it is an object from the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

you can use setter and getter methods for @Input in angular.
Please refer the below lines for reference:

```
private _data: any;
  @Input()
  set data(data) {
    this._data = data;
    console.log(this._data);
  };
```

From setter method only you can call any other method as well and can run any logic you want from there.

Comment: I tried this and it was not working for me. I think @GauriKesavaKumar is right. May be my data was not primitive although it was adding more data in object. But I got solution I just cloned and assigned. Now onChange is triggering. `this.data= cloneDeep(data);`

Comment: This isn't working for me. The spread operator in the `EventEmitter` triggered `OnChanges` but `set` in the `@Input()` didn't trigger `OnChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the data you are passing down. If it doesn't change then the ngOnChanges won't register any changes. Here's an example, you can see if a property changes multiple times then it will only trigger on the first update, but if you recreate the object it changes every time.
(see console logs in stackblitz)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qmb35h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You can do as I did and recreate the object each time to bypass this, or a more hacky way may be to keep a dummy 'count' variable that you pass down as well, and increment it each time you want the child component to register the change.

Comment: True that ngOnChanges is triggered according to the incoming data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also JSON stringify your object in the parent before passing it to child, then JSON parse the string into the original object in the child.

You don't even have to parse the string in the child. Just stringify the object in the parent, pass it through the parent HTML template alongside the object, and don't make an `@Input()` for the string in the child. `ngOnChanges` will fire and you can do stuff with the passed object.

I'm not saying this is the best solution, just that it's a solution. Using the spread operator is the solution I use.